# Hypothesis Testing (normality violated)

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, python

I have two sets of data, SetA and SetB - they are metrics of the same group from different time or paired. SetA score at 10 am and SetB score at 5 pm, same person (30 of them).

I want to check if the mean is significantly different between the two. The scores violate NORMALITY, hence, I have considered 3 tests,would love your feedback.

The tests are giving me wrong answers. My role is to see if two Sets are significant different.

First,

```py
import scipy.stats as stats

# Data
setA = [0.9995, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.9993, 0.9381, 0.6929, 0.7971,
        0.8464, 0.0220, 0.9979, 0.8584, 0.7538, 0.8027, 0.8768, 0.0231, 0.9990, 0.8611,
        0.6294, 0.7273, 0.8146, 0.0294, 0.9992, 0.8466, 0.7284, 0.7831, 0.8641, 0.0252]

setB = [0.9996, 0.9870, 0.7755, 0.8686, 0.8877, 0.0146, 0.9993, 0.9688, 0.6327, 0.7654,
        0.8163, 0.0240, 0.9992, 0.8571, 0.6735, 0.7543, 0.8366, 0.0272, 0.9989, 0.7375,
        0.6020, 0.6629, 0.8008, 0.0380, 0.9993, 0.8372, 0.7347, 0.7826, 0.8672, 0.0253]

# Perform Wilcoxon signed-rank test
statistic, p_value = stats.wilcoxon(setA, setB)

# Print results
print("Wilcoxon signed-rank test results:")
print(f"Test statistic: {statistic}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")

# Check significance level (e.g., alpha = 0.05)
alpha = 0.05
if p_value < alpha:
    print("Reject the null hypothesis: There is a significant difference between the paired samples.")
else:
    print("Fail to reject the null hypothesis: There is no significant difference between the paired samples.")
# Data
# Calculate the average mean for SetA
average_mean_setA = sum(setA) / len(setA)

# Calculate the average mean for SetB
average_mean_setB = sum(setB) / len(setB)

print(f"Average Mean for SetA: {average_mean_setA}")
print(f"Average Mean for SetB: {average_mean_setB}")''''

Wilcoxon signed-rank test results:
Test statistic: 99.0
P-value: 0.01038770331258549
Reject the null hypothesis: There is a significant difference between the paired samples.
Average Mean for SetA: 0.7305133333333331
Average Mean for SetB: 0.6991266666666668
```

Second Test - Bootstrap sampling

```py
# Calculate the observed mean difference
observed_mean_difference = np.mean(np.array(setB) - np.array(setA))

# Number of bootstrap samples
num_samples = 10000

# Initialize an array to store bootstrapped mean differences
bootstrap_mean_differences = np.zeros(num_samples)

# Perform bootstrap sampling
for i in range(num_samples):
    # Resample with replacement from the combined dataset
    combined_data = np.concatenate((setA, setB))
    resampled_data = np.random.choice(combined_data, size=len(combined_data), replace=True)
    
    # Calculate mean difference for this bootstrap sample
    bootstrap_mean_difference = np.mean(resampled_data[:len(setA)]) - np.mean(resampled_data[len(setA):])
    bootstrap_mean_differences[i] = bootstrap_mean_difference

# Calculate the p-value
p_value = np.sum(bootstrap_mean_differences >= observed_mean_difference) / num_samples

print("Bootstrap hypothesis test results:")
print(f"Observed Mean Difference: {observed_mean_difference}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")
Bootstrap hypothesis test results:
Observed Mean Difference: -0.03138666666666667
P-value: 0.6493
```

Even if the SetB is 0s, it is failing to reject NULL (no significant difference).

Permutation Test

```py
# Calculate the observed mean difference
observed_mean_difference = np.mean(setB) - np.mean(setA)

# Number of permutation samples
num_permutations = 10000

# Initialize an array to store permutation mean differences
permutation_mean_differences = np.zeros(num_permutations)

# Perform permutation sampling
for i in range(num_permutations):
    # Combine the data
    combined_data = setA + setB
    
    # Permute the combined data
    permuted_data = np.random.permutation(combined_data)
    
    # Calculate mean difference for this permutation sample
    perm_setA = permuted_data[:len(setA)]
    perm_setB = permuted_data[len(setA):]
    permutation_mean_difference = np.mean(perm_setB) - np.mean(perm_setA)
    permutation_mean_differences[i] = permutation_mean_difference

# Calculate the p-value
p_value = np.sum(permutation_mean_differences >= observed_mean_difference) / num_permutations

print("Permutation hypothesis test results:")
print(f"Observed Mean Difference: {observed_mean_difference}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")
Permutation hypothesis test results:
Observed Mean Difference: -0.031386666666666674
P-value: 0.6376
```

Comment: have you looked at repeated measures?

Comment: (1) As @Estimatetheestimators writes, you should really be looking at repeated measures models, or paired t-tests. (2) [The Wilcoxon and the t-test test very different things!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/624494/1352) (3) In your second model, you resample from the full dataset, instead of bootstrapping the difference in means (or bootstrapping the group means separately). That will not give you what you are presumably looking for, i.e., a confidence interval or a p-value for the difference in means.

Comment: "The tests are giving me wrong answers." How can you know that?

Comment: Note that the paired t-test assumes that the *differences* are normally distributed. How do you know that normality is violated? Note also that generally normality is always violated, and in many situations a t-test will work well anyway. It depends on how exactly normality is violated, i.e., whether anything goes on that will mislead the inference. Many deviations from normality are rather harmless.

Comment: @ChristianHennig - I ran Q-Q plot and Shapiro Test - Q-Q plot have very rare fit. When I populate second set with all 0s, the Bootstrap was still saying it was not significant while the avg mean diff was high.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - for bootstrap, I am establishing observed mean dff (x) of two sets then iterating n times and storing more observed mean diff then (total mean diff above and greater)  (y),  to get p-value  y/n, which is a probability metric I am testing against ..does this make sense?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your explanation, sorry... to bootstrap the difference in means, you would bootstrap the observations in both groups separately, then calculate the means of the bootstrapped data *within each group*, then take the difference, store this difference, and iterate the procedure many times. Finally you would compare the observed difference in means to the distribution of the bootstrapped differences.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - agreed, that is what I am doing with code. Not sure if there is a flaw, combined_data stores all boostrap sample then this calculates mean difference    bootstrap_mean_differences[i] = bootstrap_mean_difference. After that it is proportion.